# Wordpress loop inside of Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, loops, tabs

I'm trying to have a loop call in side of a tab in a tab group. The tabs are from bootstrap, and the only thing is that when the page first loads, the loop doesn't, you have to click on a tab to load up the content. Is there any way to make sure the loop is load on page load?

For context, this a library site, and the content are new books/music/movies listed out with an image left justified and title/author on the right.

Here is the code that I'm using.

```
 <div class="span4 pull-right">
    <h2 style="font-weight:200;">New At The Library</h2>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#books" data-toggle="tab"><h5 style="margin:0;"><i class="icon-book"></i>  New Books</h5></a></li>
  <li><a href="#cds" data-toggle="tab"><h5 style="margin:0;"><i class="icon-music"></i>  New Music</h5></a></li>
  <li><a href="#movies" data-toggle="tab"><h5 style="margin:0;"><i class="icon-film"></i>  New Films</h5></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane" id="books">
<?php query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'new-books', 'posts_per_page' => -3 ) ); ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
    <ul class="unstyled">
        <li class="clearfix">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, $arraySIZE = array('' => 120,80 ), array('class' => 'img-polaroid')); ?>
            &nbsp;
            <h4 class="pull-right" style="margin:0;"><?php the_content();?></h4>
        </li>
            <hr>
    </ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>


<div class="tab-pane" id="cds">
<?php query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'new-music', 'posts_per_page' => -3 ) ); ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
    <ul class="unstyled">
        <li class="clearfix">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, $arraySIZE = array('' => 80,80 ), array('class' => 'img-polaroid')); ?>
            &nbsp;
            <h4 class="pull-right" style="margin:0;"><?php the_content();?></h4>
        </li>
            <hr>
    </ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="movies">

<?php query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'new-movies', 'posts_per_page' => -3 ) ); ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
    <ul class="unstyled">
        <li class="clearfix">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, $arraySIZE = array('' => 120,80 ), array('class' => 'img-polaroid')); ?>
            &nbsp;
            <h4 class="pull-right" style="margin:0;"><?php the_content();?></h4>
        </li>
            <hr>
    </ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you include your code in your question, which will allow us to better help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have to declare one of the tab panes as active.  I am doing this same thing in a Bootstrap 3 build and am able to load the loop this way...

just add "active" to the first tab pane div class like so:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="books">
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Yup.That was exactly it. Thank you so much!